# Python Regex for subsetting columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe with various column names and want to pull all those that end with '-A' followed by either 1 or 2 numbers. For instance, a column name I would want returned is 'Charlie-A14'.

I tried the following

```
data.columns[data.columns.str.match('\A+\d')]
```

However, it does not return the column '2-But-1,1,1,3,3-A5'.

The columns I would want to return are: 'Hex-A14',
'2-But-1,1,1,3,3-A5', 'Hep-A16','2-Pen-1,1,1,3,3-A5','Oct-A18',
'Dec-A22', 'Dod-A26',
'(2RS,5R)-Ment-2,6,6-A3'

Comment: you want `'A\d{1,2}'` I think

Comment: `\A` is a start of  a string. `A` matches `A`. Of the `A`+digits is at the end, you need `.match(r'.*A\d{1,2}$')` or `.match(r'.*\bA\d{1,2}$')` if `A` must not be preceded with any other letter, digit or `_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\A+\d` matches a single digit at the start of a string (`\A` is an anchor that only matches the string start position).

More, [`Series.str.match()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) requires the regex to match at the start of the string.

So, you can use either

```py
.match(r'.*A\d{1,2}$')
```

or - if `A` cannot be preceded by any other word char:

```py
.match(r'.*\bA\d{1,2}$')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NYktWX/1).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `A` - an `A` letter
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches only one digit, not 1 or 2, also the '-' is not considred. Try this:

```
\-A\d{1,2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/lFMRL4/1